# How to display maximum salary from each department without using max function using joins

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

I have two tables:

- Employee, columns: fiels emp_id. emp_name, Department _id, salary.
- Department, columns: dep_id and dep_name.

I have to display the maximum salary in each department without using max function using joins.

```
select * from 
(select salary, Dense_rank() over(order by salary desc) As Rank from 
employee)
Where Rank =5;
```

I tried group by but not getting the answer.

I am a beginner in SQL queries

Comment: Updated query posted ...I have already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a partition in your call to `DENSE_RANK`:

```
SELECT dep_name, salary
FROM
(
    SELECT d.dep_name, e.salary,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY d.dep_id ORDER BY e.salary DESC) AS rnk
    FROM employee e
    INNER JOIN department d
        ON e.Department_id = d.dep_id
) t
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

The basic idea behind the `PARTITION` on the department is that we want to assign a separate rank per department to each employee in every department.  Regarding your two tables, we join employee to department to bring in department information for each employee.